# Insert multiple rows with different column names

Tags: mysql

I have query like below that updates multiple stock prices every second

```
INSERT INTO `stock` (`price`, `stock1`) VALUES ('99', '10') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `stock1` = `stock1` + 10 , `stock1-C` = `stock1-C` + 1 ;
INSERT INTO `stock` (`price`, `stock2`) VALUES ('120', '10') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `stock2` = `stock2` + 10 , `stock2-C` = `stock2-C` + 1 ;
```

Like this I get around 50 price in a second , Is there any way to insert all this in single query ?

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
  (`price`, `stock1`),
  (`price`, `stock2`)
VALUES
  ('99', '10') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `stock1` = `stock1` + 10 , `stock1-C` = `stock1-C` + 1 , 
  ('120', '10') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `stock2` = `stock2` + 10 , `stock2-C` = `stock2-C` + 1 ,
```

Is there anything possible like above query ? for inserting 50 different query in single go.

Comment: What is the duplicate key? Post the table's definition and sample data to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include both columns `stock1` and `stock2` in the `INSERT` statement, with `null` as the value of the column for which there is no value to supply:

```
INSERT INTO stock (price, stock1, stock2) VALUES
  ('99', '10', null), 
  ('120', null, '10')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  
  stock1 = COALESCE(stock1 + VALUES(stock1), stock1), 
  `stock1-C` = `stock1-C` + (VALUES(stock1) IS NOT NULL),
  stock2 = COALESCE(stock2 + VALUES(stock2), stock2), 
  `stock2-C` = `stock2-C` + (VALUES(stock2) IS NOT NULL)
```

Of course, there is the problem of the initial values of `stock1-C` and `stock2-C` for which you do not supply any values in your query, so they are `null` in the new rows, unless you have defined default values for them.

Comment: Thank you ! is there is limit on how big the query can be ?

Comment: @Graciewilliams the max size of the query sent from client side to the server is defined to 16MB but it can be increased. Read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: hi your code works good,but if i use  ('99', '11, null), ('99', null, '11') ,(duplicate price)  it should add 1 for stock1-C and stock2-C , but it is incrementing twice  , adding +2 in both

Comment: @Graciewilliams for the 1st row: ('99', '11', null) stock1-c will be incremented by 1, but stock2-c will not be affected because `(VALUES(stock2) IS NOT NULL)` is equal to 0, so `stock2-c + 0` will leave stock2-c unmodified. Then if you insert ('99', null, '11') will not affect stock1-c for the same reason and will increase only stock2-c. I don't know how you use the code in my answer. Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7

Comment: HI  , I will mark this answer and post new question

Comment: please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66245333/increment-multiple-columns-on-duplicate , I have explained clearly

Answer (score 1):

You have to split the inserts, but so you can add multiple values

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
  (`price`, `stock1`)
VALUES
  ('99', '10'),('120', '10')  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `stock1` = VALUES(`stock1`) + 10 , `stock1-C` = VALUES(`stock1-C`) + 1 ;



INSERT INTO MyTable
  (`price`, `stock2`)
  VALUES
    ('120', '10'),('121', '10'),('122', '10') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `stock2` = VALUES(`stock2`) + 10 , `stock2-C` = VALUES(`stock2-C`) + 1 ;
```

Comment: multiple insert does not slow down the system ?

Comment: There are the general considerations for bulk insert, but you talked about 50 rows, so not really.