# Update and Increment multiple columns on duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following query to insert multiple values and on duplicate need to update the columns

```
 INSERT INTO stock (price, stock1, stock2) VALUES
  ('99', '10', 0), 
  ('120', 0, '10')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  
  stock1 = COALESCE(stock1 + VALUES(stock1), stock1), 
  `stock1-C` = `stock1-C` + (VALUES(stock1) IS NOT NULL),
  stock2 = COALESCE(stock2 + VALUES(stock2), stock2), 
  `stock2-C` = `stock2-C` + (VALUES(stock2) IS NOT NULL)
```

Running this query first time should add (+) **column** existing value with new value and increment existing **column-C** value with 1 , let me try to explain with some examples

Following is the default table , where **price** is the unique column and remaining columns have default value 0

| price | stock1 | stock1-C | stock2 | stock2-C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Running following values creates rows like this

```
('99', '10', 0), 
('120', 0, '12')
```

| price | stock1 | stock1-C | stock2 | stock2-C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 120 | 0 | 0 | 12 | 0 |

Running the same values like this again should add **column** with new value and increment the **column-C** column

```
('99', '10', 0), 
('120', 0, '12')
```

| price | stock1 | stock1-C | stock2 | stock2-C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 20 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 120 | 0 | 0 | 24 | 1 |

***Expected Result***  :

Above two query works perfectly for my code , now lets try inserting duplicate price

```
('150', '55', 0), 
  ('150', 0, '56')
```

Since there is no 150 in price before it should give :

| price | stock1 | stock1-C | stock2 | stock2-C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 20 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 120 | 0 | 0 | 24 | 1 |
| 150 | 55 | 0 | 56 | 0 |

And running again should update rows like :

```
 ('150', '10', 0), 
 ('150', 0, '10')
```

| price | stock1 | stock1-C | stock2 | stock2-C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 20 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 120 | 0 | 0 | 24 | 1 |
| 150 | 65 | 1 | 66 | 1 |

***Actual Result :***

But  first time rows are getting updated with 1 and next time its updated with 3

('150', '55', 0),
('150', 0, '56')

| price | stock1 | stock1-C | stock2 | stock2-C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 20 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 120 | 0 | 0 | 24 | 1 |
| 150 | 55 | 1 | 56 | 1 |

And 2nd time when I run  I get like this

('150', '55', 0),
('150', 0, '56')

| price | stock1 | stock1-C | stock2 | stock2-C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 20 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 120 | 0 | 0 | 24 | 1 |
| 150 | 55 | 3 | 56 | 3 |

Whereas If i do that in multiple query it works fine

```
INSERT INTO `bankvolume` (`price`, `stock1`) VALUES (100, 10) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `stock1` = COALESCE(`stock1` + VALUES(`stock1`), `stock1`), 
  `stock1-C` = `stock1-C` + (VALUES(`stock1`) IS NOT NULL);


INSERT INTO `bankvolume` (`price`, `stock2`) VALUES (100, 10) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `stock2` = COALESCE(`stock2` + VALUES(`stock2`), `stock2`), 
  `stock2-C` = `stock2-C` + (VALUES(`stock2`) IS NOT NULL);
```

I want to combine both into single ,

P.s : I have more than 50 stocks to update in single query , that is why trying to optimise my code , thank you.

Comment: If you insert ('99', '10', null) why do you expect 0 for stock1-C, stock2 and stock2-C? Have you defined these columns as NOT NULL with default value 0? Post the definition of the table.

Comment: Yes columns are defined with default value as 0 , I have updated it in question

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=72a92ca580544bd0362c0772faf73748?

Comment: Yes , check this now https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=05c0f51fc16bc6c575feac88cae3cb1d

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the columns are not nullable you must pass `0`s instead of `null`s for the columns that you don't want to supply values in the `INSERT` statements and use comparisons to `0` instead of `null`:

```
INSERT INTO stock (price, stock1, stock2) VALUES
  ('99', '10', 0), 
  ('120', 0, '12')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  `stock1-C` = `stock1-C` + (VALUES(stock1) <> 0 AND stock1 <> 0),
  stock1 = stock1 + VALUES(stock1), 
  `stock2-C` = `stock2-C` + (VALUES(stock2) <> 0 AND stock2 <> 0),
  stock2 = stock2 + VALUES(stock2)
```

Result:

| price | stock1 | stock1-C | stock2 | stock2-C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 120 | 0 | 0 | 12 | 0 |

Then again:

```
INSERT INTO stock (price, stock1, stock2) VALUES
  ('99', '10', 0), 
  ('120', 0, '12')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  `stock1-C` = `stock1-C` + (VALUES(stock1) <> 0 AND stock1 <> 0),
  stock1 = stock1 + VALUES(stock1), 
  `stock2-C` = `stock2-C` + (VALUES(stock2) <> 0 AND stock2 <> 0),
  stock2 = stock2 + VALUES(stock2)
```

Result:

| price | stock1 | stock1-C | stock2 | stock2-C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 20 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 120 | 0 | 0 | 24 | 1 |

Then:

```
INSERT INTO stock (price, stock1, stock2) VALUES
  ('150', '55', 0), 
  ('150', 0, '56')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  `stock1-C` = `stock1-C` + (VALUES(stock1) <> 0 AND stock1 <> 0),
  stock1 = stock1 + VALUES(stock1), 
  `stock2-C` = `stock2-C` + (VALUES(stock2) <> 0 AND stock2 <> 0),
  stock2 = stock2 + VALUES(stock2)
```

Result:

| price | stock1 | stock1-C | stock2 | stock2-C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 20 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 120 | 0 | 0 | 24 | 1 |
| 150 | 55 | 0 | 56 | 0 |

Then:

```
INSERT INTO stock (price, stock1, stock2) VALUES
  ('150', '10', 0), 
  ('150', 0, '10')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  `stock1-C` = `stock1-C` + (VALUES(stock1) <> 0 AND stock1 <> 0),
  stock1 = stock1 + VALUES(stock1), 
  `stock2-C` = `stock2-C` + (VALUES(stock2) <> 0 AND stock2 <> 0),
  stock2 = stock2 + VALUES(stock2)
```

Result:

| price | stock1 | stock1-C | stock2 | stock2-C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 20 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 120 | 0 | 0 | 24 | 1 |
| 150 | 65 | 1 | 66 | 1 |

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bc7d49aedb4fe62a9f5f8e281d20dfcc).